# How to convert a .so file for IA 32-bit system to one for ARM systems

Tags: shared-libraries, processing, libraries

I'm currently trying to get a processing sketch I've made to run on my raspberry pi, but whenever I run it it essentially tells me that a library I am using (Game Control Plus) only works with IA 32-Bit systems.

The full error is `UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/sketchbook/libraries/GameControlPlus/library/libjinput-linux.so: /home/pi/sketchbook/libraries/GameControlPlus/library/libjinput-linux.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)`

I was wondering if there was a way to convert the .so file to one that works with an ARM system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was a way to convert the .so file

There is *not*.

You need to rebuild this game using a compiler which targets ARM and Pi (fortunately for you, the game is open-source, so you could at least in theory do that).

Comment: Best suggestion I have found so far is from Quark (the author of the processing Game Control Plus library).   https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/15350/gamecontrolplus-on-raspberry-pi          It seems we need a libjinput-linux.so which has been compiled for the ARM32 architecture currently (2021_08_08)  used on the Pi family.